# Angular $http.get and Express req.body is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have problem with req.body with sending data using $http.get. When i change in my route in routes.js method from GET to POST, and also change in my service to $http.post, everything work fine, but with GET i can't send any data to my sever in node. Anyone has any idea ?

server.js

```
// modules =================================================
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var mongoose       = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var path = require('path');

// configuration ===========================================


var db = require('./config/db');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 
mongoose.connect(db.url); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 



// routes ==================================================
require('./app/routes')(app,__dirname);

// start app ===============================================
app.listen(port);   
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);   
exports = module.exports = app;
```

./app/routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app, __dirname) {

    var Card     = require('./models/card');

    app.post('/create', function(req, res) {
        var card = new Card();

        card.polishWord = req.body.polishWord;
        card.polishDescription = req.body.polishDescription;
        card.englishWord = req.body.englishWord;
        card.englishDescription = req.body.englishDescription;
        card.category = req.body.category;

        card.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({message: 'Card created'});
        });
    });

    app.get('/take', function(req, res) {
        var condition = req.body.condition || {};
        console.log(req.headers);
        console.log('______________');
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log('______________');
        /*TODO :: Czemu nie odbiera parametrow GET*/
        Card.find(condition,function(err, cards) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(cards);
        });
    });



    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile('/public/index.html',{"root": __dirname});
    });
};
```

./public/js/services/CardService ( part )

```
cardService.getAllCards = function(){
    return $http.get('/take',{params: {condition:{"category":"animal"}},data: {condition:{"category":"animal"}}});
};
```

req.headers

```
{ host: 'localhost:8080',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36',
  referer: 'http://localhost:8080/card',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
  'accept-language': 'pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
  cookie: '_ga=GA1.1.1073910751.1465203314' }
```

.package.json ( dependencies )

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "mongoose": "4.4.20",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "method-override": "~2.0.2"
  },
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: when you want to use GET method, req.params will help you to get parameters. req.body is used when we use POST method.

Comment: can you please use params and give it a try it should work.

Comment: i used req.params 5 minut ago, and the same result. :(

Comment: but i look into req, and find it inside
`query: { condition: '{"category":"animal"}' },`
could me someone explain why ?

Comment: @AmitShah `params` is wrong, that's for namespaced routes. You should be using `req.query` for GET requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.body` was undefined because you issued a `'GET'` request from `$http.get('/take')`. What you sent to the server are [query parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). An example of query parameters would be:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm?filter=all&sort=active`

where `filter` and `sort` are the query parameters with the values `'all'` and `'active'` respectively.

To access query parameters in an Express server, you'll need to use the [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) object. It contains the query parameters and their corresponding values. The `req.query` object for the request to `'/take'` would look like this:

```
{
  condition: {
    category: "animal"
  }
}
```